# ¿Qué significa "el bueno de alguien"?

Tags: significado, locuciones

En los libros de Javier Sierra he encontrado más que una vez la expresión de la pregunta.

Aquí viene un ejemplo del libro "Las puertas templarias":

> Ni por un segundo **el bueno de Jean** de Avallon imaginó que combatir con la coraza de la fe fuera algo tan real, tan próximo y tan peligroso a la vez.

¿Qué significa esta expresión y cómo se lo puede traducir al inglés (o alemán)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el diccionario, en este caso se debería apelar a la siguiente acepción de "[bueno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6EawoZ6)":

> 6. adj. irón. Dicho de una persona: Simple, bonachona o chocante. Usado más como sustantivo. *El bueno de Fulano.*

Por el ejemplo que da el DLE se podría decir que coincide con tu frase. A mí particularmente me choca que la expresión se use siempre en tono irónico (como indica la definición), y no se pueda usar en sentido literal (una persona buena de verdad, más que simple o bonachona).

La expresión en inglés que se me ocurre como traducción es:

> Good old Jean

La web de SpanishCentral.com (del mismo grupo que el Merriam-Webster) parece [confirmar esta traducción](http://www.spanishcentral.com/translate/good) (ver entrada 31 en *good* como adjetivo).

Comment: La construcción artículo determinante + adjetivo (o sustantivo descriptivo) + "de" + sustantivo (común o propio) suele ser irónica cuando el adjetivo (o sustantivo) posterior al artículo tiene connotación positiva. Cuando el adjetivo ya posee una connotación negativa, el uso deja de ser irónico: "El  genio de Juan", "El imbécil de Juan".

Answer (score 3):

Ofrezco una idea tentativa, esperando que me den feedback los demás.

Creo que

> el ____(adj.)____ de ____(sust.)_____

donde el adjetivo describe a una persona, es una construcción de uso general, inspirando en el lector alguna reacción emocional.  (Un adjetivo que describe un color, por ejemplo, no funcionaría.)  Ejemplos:

1. El cochino de mi vecino me despertó en la madrugada.

Hay dos interpretaciones: Mi vecino es un cochino (es decir, es una persona tan sucia como un cochino) y me despertó temprano; mi vecino tiene un cochino que me despertó temprano.  (Cuando usé esta frase en una ocasión, tratando de expresar la segunda idea, mis compañeros se rieron y me explicaron la primera idea.)

La emoción que nos inspira: molestia y disgusto (para con el vecino).

2. "Apenas cuatro años después, un infarto cardiaco dejaba viuda, y con la soledad como única acompañante, a la buena de doña Matilde." *El retrato del general* de María Pilar Queralt del Hierro (publicado en *[Relatos del Pasado](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WT53KII)*).

Si buscas la frase exacta en google, "la buena de doña," encontrarás muchos ejemplos así.

La emoción que nos inspira: condolencia.

3. Escogí un adjetivo al azar, "ansiosa," y busqué con google la frase exacta, "la ansiosa de" y encontré: "[Alfredo] revisa unos mails; contesta dos que le ofrecen juntarse para conversar de proyectos «grandiosos»; le responde a la ansiosa de la Conchita Ossa" en *Sudor* de Alberto Fuguet.

La emoción que nos inspira: impaciencia con la señora que nos agobia con su ansiedad.

4. Otro intento con un adjetivo escogido al azar ("al amable de"): "... mis dos únicos y queridos nietos, cuyas fotos enternecieron al amable de Luis Ángel."  (Lo encontré en *[Pronombres Personales](https://books.google.com/books?id=dpEeAQAAIAAJ&q=%22al%20amable%20de%22&dq=%22al%20amable%20de%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW47vL86bTAhUK7YMKHfbsApAQ6AEILDAB)* de Isaac E. Chocrón.)

Como es apenas un fragmento, no se puede estar seguro, pero quizás en este caso la emoción que inspira es la ternura por Luis Ángel por su paciencia y bondad.

Pidiste una traducción al inglés y alemán de "el bueno de Jean de Avallon."  Leí varios párrafos del [cuento](http://www.megustaleer.com/fragmentos/sec/0093865/index.html), para ver el contexto.  Se trata de un pobre ingenuo que llega a las cruzadas en 1125, sin esperar lo sangrienta que sería la batalla.  Entonces aquí sí es un poquito irónico el tono.

> inglés: Not for a second did the good (naïve, poor, simple) Jean imagine....
>
> alemán: Nicht für einen einzigen Moment hat der gute (naive, arme, einfache) Jean sich vorgestellt....